# Sorting elements in string with Python

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort string, and I came up with the following function.

```
def mysort(comb_): 
    str = [] 
    size = len(comb_) 
    for c in comb_: 
        str.append(c) 
    str.sort() 
    return ''.join(str)
```

Is there any way to make it compact?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
return ''.join(sorted(comb_))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It cannot get more succinct (or idiomatic) than that.  Disregarding the strange underscore in the variable name, of course.

Answer (score 3):

```
def sortstr(comb_):
    return ''.join(sorted(comb_))
```

e:f;b :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a string back do this:

```
def sort_string(string):
    return "".join(sorted(string))
```

But if you want a list back, do this:

```
def sort_string(string):
    return sorted(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sort_string(s):
    def sort_string_to_a_list(s):
        return sorted(s, lambda x,y: cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()) or cmp(x,y))
    sorted_list = sort_string_to_a_list(s)
    return ''.join(sorted_list)
```